# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'PCAComputeVar'

Tags: python, opencv

I was working on a project on facial recognition using asift, which does PCA whitening before it processes the image. One of my friends downloaded a code and gave it to me for execution, so we have something to start with. But however, on execution, I got an error, which said -

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'PCAComputeVar'
```

On Googling, I found that PCAComputeVar is supported mainly in opencv 2. However, I couldn't find anything in opencv 3. I don't want to downgrade to opencv 2, because there are some features supported only in opencv 3.

Is there any method by which I can access opencv 2 libraries from opencv3? If not, atleast is there any function in opencv 3, which does something similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to their [3.2 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0ad1147fbcdb256f2e14ae2bfb8c991d), it was renamed to `cv2.PCACompute()`.

More details on the parameters can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html).